# General form for the recurrence relation $a_{n+1} - a_n = 4^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

So... I just learned about discrete, and I'm trying to solve this problem, finding the general term I guess : 
$$
a_1 = 1,\qquad a_{n+1} - a_n = 4^n\, \text{ for all } n\geq 1
$$

I looked at some examples and found that the solution is $a_n = \frac{1}{3}(4^n - 1)$.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: $a_{n+1} =a_1+ \sum_{i=1}^n(a_{i+1} - a_{i}) =1+ \sum_{i=1}^n 4^i = \sum_{i=0}^n 4^i$. Looks like the partial sum of a geometric series

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).

Answer (score 1):

Start with what you know: for *every* $n\geq 1$,
$$
a_{n+1}-a_n = 4^n \tag{1}
$$
Now, what happens if you sum this equation (1), for $n$ ranging from $1$ to some $N\geq 1$?
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (a_{n+1}-a_n) = \sum_{n=1}^N 4^n \tag{2}
$$
But the left-hand-side is a **telescopic** series:
$$
\sum_{n=1}^N (a_{n+1}-a_n) = (a_{N+1} - a_N) + (a_N-a_{N-1})+\dots + (a_2-a_1) = a_{N+1} - a_1
$$
but the right-hand-side is a [geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula), equal to $$
4\cdot\frac{4^N-1}{4-1} = \frac{4}{3}(4^N - 1)
$$

Therefore, you end up with
$
a_{N+1} - 1 = \frac{4}{3}(4^N - 1)
$ or equivalently
$$
a_{N+1} = \frac{1}{3}(4^{N+1} - 1)
$$
for $N\geq 1$.

Comment: why does the equivalent answer to  a(N+1) - 1 = 4/3(4^N - 1) is a(N+1) = ⅓(4^N+1 - 1)

Comment: Expand the right-hand side in two terms; add 1 to both sides.

Comment: @AJTech Is it clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Let a_n=c(lamda)^n be a solution to a_n+1 - a_n = 4^n
so we have c(lamda)^n)(lamda-1)=4^n
which is c(lamda-1)=(4/lamda)^n
so if lamda is 4 RHS is 1 so c(4-1)=1 so c=1/3
therefore a_n=1/3 (4)^n solves a_n+1 - a_n = 4^n
yet a_1=1 so then a_1= 1/3 (4) needs to be adjusted by 1/3
so we have a_n=1/3 (4^n-1)